# Custom Dates for every date

Tags: titles, datetime

In LaTeX you can output the current date by writing `\today` in your document. This is very handy if you want to set the date of the document to today. Normally I write the preamble of my documents like that:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

# \usepackage{} and things like that

\title{Title goes here}
\author{Nick Lehmann}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

This is very handy because in most cases I don't have to care about the formatting of the date. But how is it possible to insert a custom date what will be formatted depending on the language setting? Is there something like `\date{\custom_date{year}{month}{day}}` that produces dates like `1st January 2001` when using babel with the British option?

Comment: check package isodate.

Comment: Thank you for the useful reference. Please answer the question next so I can accept your answer and mark this question as answered. By the way, you will then get the proper reputation.

Comment: I tend to use [`datetime`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime), sometimes together with [`datenumber`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datenumber) and [`fp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fp). The combination of the last two is only needed if you want to calculate dates, though. The first alone handles language-dependent formatting of dates (overriding `babel`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check package `isodate`. It provides various output formats and language support.